# Command to update local file to see merge conflicts

Tags: git

What is the command used to show both my local changes and the remote's difference in my editor, i.e. how do I update my local files with the merge conflicts (the HEAD and the <<<<<<) ?

I think it is something to do with git fetch HEAD remote but I can't seem to remember

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Do you want to resolve merge conflicts, or do you want to pull the latest remote changes?

Comment: i want to overlay my local code with remote differences so i can resolve a merge conflict. currently i can see the diff in my terminal window but i want to do this in my local editor

Comment: Egit in eclipse has some feature like that. But I later on realized that its not the right way of resolving conflicts... Do `git pull` let git try the merge and if in conflict, it will add content and markers in the local working copy. Check the markers, fix the conflicts and commit the merged file...